# 1PI effective action and Action generated through Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, non-perturbative, 1pi-effective-action

In standard lectures on advanced QFT one learnt that performing Legendre transformation leads to effective actions generating one-particle-irreducible (1PI) diagrams, which is encoded by Schwinger-Dyson equation. From the book by Altland and Simons, Hubbard-Stratonovich transformation provides an alternative approach to the diagrammatic perturbation exploiting Schwinger-Dyson equation or Bethe-Salpeter equation. I feel confused trying to put the two techniques in the same picture and would like to ask how these two are related if there is any? Or is there a criterion on when to apply one of the two techniques? It seems that I don’t really understand the two concepts. (cf. Altland and Simons’ book (2nd edition) p. 250)

Explicitly, in the book, (eq. 6.6) is compared with the result (eq. 5.34) calculated from random phase approximation:

$S_{eff} = \frac{1}{2TL^3}\sum_{q}\phi_q\left(V_{eff.}^{-1}\right)\phi_{-q} + \mathcal{O}\left(\phi^4\right)$ with
$V_{eff.} = \frac{1}{V\left(\mathbf{q}\right)^{-1} - \Pi_q}$ and $\Pi_q$ is the polarization operator.

Basically, the self-energy term emerges from both the calculations done in chapter 5 and that in chapter 6. It feels like one obtains 1PI without performing Legendre transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To derive (5.34), one has to compare contributions $F^{(2),1}$ and $F^{(2),2}$. After careful comparison, you can conclude that $F^{(2),2}$ is finite, whereas $F^{(2),1}$ is divergent. As we have been taught by our Fathers, the divergent contributions are important, finite contributions are not so interested. It means that at this step you have specified the sub-class of diagram (so-called ring diagrams), which is important for the problem and now you goal is to perform summation over this diagrams. The summation gives screened interaction (5.34),
$$V_{\text{eff}}(q)=\frac{1}{V({\bf q})^{-1}-\Pi_q},$$
where $\Pi_q$ is the polarizaiton operator,
$$\Pi_q=\frac{2T}{L^3}\sum_p G_pG_{p+q}.$$
In this calculation you have dealt with free energy $F$, which is related to partition function as $F=-T\ln\mathcal{Z}$ (see p. 211).

You can achieve the same result by performing decoupling of quartic non-local interaction (Coulomb) in direct channel. To do it, you introduce a new field $\phi$, which is *effective*. Performing all the calculations, you reproduce the result obtained by RPA. To be honest, I do not see here Legendre transformation.

There is some similarity with 1PI, because in RPA you choose the concrete type of diagrams (ring diagrams) and perform summation over them because they are dominant.

P.S.: It seems nice to *write equations* in your questions, because sometimes it is hard to open book and go through pages. For instance, you can write down at which step you suspect Legendre transformation.

Let me also draw you attention onto beautiful book ["Green's functions. Theory and practice"](http://www.mit.edu/%7Elevitov/book/) by L. Levitov & A. Shytov (unfortunately, I do not about the translation from Russion to English, but you can also check [this course page](https://www.nordita.org/%7Ezarembo/CondMat2015/))

Comment: Thanks! I somehow assumed the ring diagrams to be all of 1PI. May I say HS transformation leads to expansion in terms of the ring diagrams, just like Legendre transformation leads to expansion in terms of 1PI diagrams?

Comment: @JinH , in my view, you can say the following: when we use HS in a **specific channel** (in our case it is direct channel), we take into account a certain types of diagrams, that are relevant for our task. In this sense it is quite similar to 1PI, because we sum over sub-class of diagram, only in this sense!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, "effective action" has many different meanings in QFT. One is the effective action $\Gamma$ (sometimes called the "quantum action") that generates 1PI vertices, and is given by a Legendre transform of the generating function of the correlation functions. Note that this effective action, if computed exactly, describes the physics at all scales, since all the degrees of freedom have been integrated out to compute it.

Another is any action obtained by integrating out some (usually microscopic) degrees of freedom: from integrating massive modes (such as gauge bosons in the electroweak theory), integrating short-range fluctuations a la Wilson, or integrating fermions after performing a HS transformation. "Effective" here just means that the obtained action effectively describes the remaining degrees of freedom. However, the latter still have to be integrated out to fully describe the physics.

TLDR: HS effective action is completely different from Legendre transform effective action. Doing a HS transformation has absolutely nothing to do with doing a Legendre transformion!

Comment: Let me add a minor comment: Schwinger-Dyson & Bethe-Salpeter equations are conceptually the same. With help of S-D or B-S you can develop some intuition what happends in your complicated theory and how you can simplify it. If you speak about the chapters devoted to collective phenomena (especially, about superconductivity), the Ginzburg-Landau action is effective in sense that one has introduced a new field, which arises as effective description of diffifcult theory. The same holds for plasma theory of electron gas